# Why can't we **unsplat 'self' into a method?

Tags: python, methods, python-2.x

```
>>> class Potato(object):
...     def method(self, spam):
...         print self, spam
... 
>>> spud = Potato()
```

Works:

```
>>> Potato.method(spud, **{'spam': 123})
<__main__.Potato object at 0x7f86cd4ee9d0> 123
```

Doesn't work:

```
>>> Potato.method(**{'self': spud, 'spam': 123})
# TypeError
```

But why not?  I thought 'self' was just a convention, and there was nothing intrinsically special about this argument?

Comment: This is an interesting question. A thought: the convention is that `self` is the 1st argument, not that it's called `self`. Perhaps it doesn't expect to be unpacked by name, but by position

Comment: You get the same problem with `Potato.method(self=spud, spam=123)`. The splat is not really the issue.

Comment: It is precisely because `self` is only a convention that you can't do this.  Because the name `self` has no special status, Python only knows which argument is `self` because it is *first* in the argument list, so it must be passed positionally.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Theoretically, the method wrapper object could detect what the name is of the first argument, but that's just not worth the extra effort, as calling unbound methods directly is not the norm.

Comment: This is funny, because when I tried to specify a previously-instantiated spud as the default for 'self' in the method, I get the amusing message:  `TypeError: unbound method method() must be called with Potato instance as first argument (got Potato instance instead)`  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python 2's `instancemethod` wrapper object insists on inspecting the first *positional argument*, and that check does not support keyword arguments, *full stop*:

```
>>> Potato.method(self=spud, spam=123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method method() must be called with Potato instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Note that I did not use argument unpacking there!

You can use positional arguments just fine:

```
>>> Potato.method(*(spud,), **{'spam': 123})
<__main__.Potato object at 0x1002b57d0> 123
```

or you can access the original function object:

```
>>> Potato.method.__func__(**{'self': spud, 'spam': 123})
<__main__.Potato object at 0x1002b57d0> 123
```

to bypass this limitation.

Python 3 no longer uses a method wrapper for unbound methods; the underlying function is returned directly instead.

Comment: Source reference: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9438a8aa3622/Objects/classobject.c#l2548 Note the `self = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(arg, 0);` on line 2561 with no attempt to check the `kw` dict.

Comment: @user2357112: and why *should* it? It'd have to introspect the unwrapped function to see what the name is of the first argument, all to support an extreme edge-case easily worked around by just unwrapping the method object instead.

Comment: Is that just cpython implementation detail?  Would it still be called "python" if you _did_ dig around in the kwargs to look for a kwarg matching the argument name of the first arg in argspec?  _edit:_  the answer to this question is addressed in the duplicate linked.

Comment: @wim: the [User-defined methods section of the data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#index-35) describes the behaviour as *When an unbound user-defined method object is called, the underlying function (`im_func`) is called, with the restriction that the first argument must be an instance of the proper class (`im_class`) or of a derived class thereof* with no caveat that it is a CPython implementation detail.